# how to calculate number of datapoints within a given time interval?

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe with one column which is a timestamp. I have converted that column to a datetime object using pandas **to_datetime()** method. However what I want is to `count, for each time stamp, the number of timestamps that fall between this timestamp and prior 15 minutes`.

> For example: If a timestamp is (2018,7,6,13,55) [year,month, day,
>   hour, minute format], then I want to **count** the number of timestamps
>   (or datapoints) that fall between this timestamp and the timestamp
>   (2018,7,6,13,40).

It is easy to see what needs to be done, but it involves repeatedly going back and forth over the dataset. I have close to 750,000 datapoints and what I am thinking is not efficient.

How can I do it efficiently?

Any suggestion/hint would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer given by @Aditya is very good and educational despite the fact that the `how` is deprecated. So the right answer would be as follows:

`df.resample("15T").agg({'count':'sum'})`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this doing [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

- First we should index on the timestamp column, if you have not already done so:

  `df.set_index('time', inplace=True)`
- The we will add a temporary column(you need something to aggregate on):

  `df['count'] = 1`
- And finally resample as needed:

  `df.resample('15T', how='sum')`

Or

Since You can subtract them easily thanks to Pandas; 
let's say you have sorted your time-stamps, now you can easily iterate and use `isin` combined with `pd.timedelta()` ...

Something like this should probably work since

`current_time<=current_time+timedelta(15 mins)`, you can count then using `isin` and `.size()` etc...